# I had a problem with python library pikepdf

Tags: python, pikepdf

When trying to install the python moduel pikepdf using pip, this error pops up:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pikepdf
  Building wheel for pikepdf (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pikepdf (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [54 lines of output]
      ...
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\src\qpdf
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPOINTERHOLDER_TRANSITION=4 -IC:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dpc9ltd5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include "-IC:\Program Files\Python310\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python310\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpsrc/qpdf\annotation.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\src/qpdf\annotation.obj /EHsc /bigobj /std:c++17
      annotation.cpp
      src/qpdf\annotation.cpp(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'qpdf/Constants.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pikepdf
Failed to build pikepdf
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pikepdf, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Creating the wheel fails due to a missing header file:

```
src/qpdf\annotation.cpp(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'qpdf/Constants.h': No such file or directory
```

This is for pikepdf v6.0.0. My previous version was v4.0.1.post1, which worked fine.

Is this something that can be remedied from my side?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Solution for Macbook, M1

```
brew install qpdf
```

After it use

```
pip install pikepdf
```

Solution from https://github.com/pikepdf/pikepdf/issues/274

Answer (score 1):

Just list all versions available for pidepdf:

```
pip index versions pikepdf
```

Pick one and install it:

```
pip install pikepdf==5.6.1
```

Check back in a later version whether this is resolved.
Issues like these can be reported in their tracker: https://github.com/pikepdf/pikepdf/issues

The problem listed is known. From https://github.com/pikepdf/pikepdf/issues/390:

> pikepdf 6 requires qpdf 11 and drops compatibility for all earlier
> versions. [...] Binary wheel status: Windows support is currently
> blocked by [...]

Comment: This helped me.  Upto pikepdf 0.7.x no errors on missing headers so I downgraded to that from 0.8.x.

Answer (score -2):

I had to upgrade the pip package and then run

```
pip install --upgrade pip

pip3 install pikepdf
```